# use a for loop applying a condition to upload multiple files in SAS

Tags: sas

I generate  a table SAS

[image]

which contains the name of files in a PATH. In the next step I have to go through this table and use `Proc import` to import all these files checking a condition namely:

```
if  scan(f_name, 1, 'K')= looking_date_Num
```

where `looking_date_Num` is coming from another table
[image]

How can I use a for loop applying the condition to upload all these DAT data?

Comment: Write a macro to `proc import`, and then use one of the suggestions in the linked duplicate to call that macro.  SAS has no "for loop", fyi, the similar loop in SAS is "do loop".

Comment: @Joe, where can I find this "duplicate"?

Comment: At the top of your question, there is now a box "This question already has an answer here:" and a link.  Or, in the "Linked" box to the right.  You also should've gotten a notification about this.

Comment: thanks, yes I got a notification but without link, I will try it thanks again!

Comment: Piece of advice, don't use proc import, write a data step since you have many files with what I assume is a consistent structure. You'll save yourself work down the road.